# How to Find The Intersection of two Bags

Tags: c++

Ok so I have this code down.

Bag interface

```
#ifndef BAGINTERFACE_H
#define    BAGINTERFACE_H

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface
{
    public:

    virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual bool add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;
    virtual bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;
    virtual void clear() = 0;
    virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;
    virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;
    virtual std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;
}; 

#endif    /* BAGINTERFACE_H */
```

Bag
     #ifndef BAG_H
    #define    BAG_H

```
#include "BagInterface.h"

template <class ItemType>
class Bag: public BagInterface<ItemType>
{

public:

    int getCurrentSize() const { return v.size(); }
    bool isEmpty() const { return v.empty(); }
    bool add(const ItemType& newEntry) { v.push_back(newEntry); return true; }
    bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry) { std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), anEntry); return true; }
    void clear() { v.clear(); }
    int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const { return std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), anEntry); }
    bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const { return true; }
    std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const { return v; }

private:

  std::vector<ItemType> v;

};

#endif    /* BAG_H */
```

and my actual program main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> // For cout and cin
#include <string> // For string objects
#include "Bag.h" // For ADT bag
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string clubs[] = { "Joker", "Ace", "Two", "Three",
"Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
"Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack",
"Queen", "King" };
// Create our bag to hold cards
Bag<string> grabBag;
Bag<string> dumpBag;

grabBag.add(clubs[1]);
grabBag.add(clubs[2]);
grabBag.add(clubs[4]);
grabBag.add(clubs[8]);
grabBag.add(clubs[10]);
grabBag.add(clubs[12]);

dumpBag.add(clubs[3]);
dumpBag.add(clubs[5]);
dumpBag.add(clubs[7]);
dumpBag.add(clubs[9]);
dumpBag.add(clubs[10]);
dumpBag.add(clubs[12]);

Bag<string> Itersection(Bag<string> bagToCompare){


    return grabBag;
}


return 0;
}; // end main
```

I am trying to find the intersection  of two bags which will be a new bag containing the entries that occur in both of the original two bags. So basically I need to design and specify a method  intersection that returns as a new bag the intersection of the bag receiving the call to the method and the bag that is the method’s one argument.
Suppose that bag1 and bag2 are bags; bag1 contains the strings a , b , and c ; and bag2 contains the strings b , b , d , and e . The expression bag1.intersection(bag2) returns a bag containing only the string b.

I already made the two bags to compare to each other but I'm not too sure how to design the intersection method.

Any help would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you define the intersection of two bags?  What if bag A contains `"Joker"` 3 times, and bag B contains `"Joker"` 2 times?  How many times is `"Joker"` in the intersection of A and B?

Comment: If you define `contains` in a meaningful way, you've solved half of the problem.

Comment: @robmayoff Well suppose that bag1  and  bag2  are bags;  bag1  contains the strings  a , b , and  c ; and  bag2  contains the strings  b , b , d , and  e . The expression  bag1.intersection(bag2)  returns a bag containing only the string  b.

Comment: @JohnPeterson So if bag 1 contains n times the value V, and bag 2 contains m times the value V, the intersection of bag 1 and bag 2 should contain min(n, m) times the value V?

Comment: @Thomas Then the intersection of bag1 and bag2 will contain m times V if m is greater than n or n time V if n is greater than m.

Comment: If bag `A` contains `"Joker"` 3 times, how many times does `"Joker"` appear in `A.toVector()`?  3 times?  1 time?  Some other number?

Comment: @JohnPeterson That contradicts your previous comment and any meaningful definition of "intersection". According to your definition the bag should contain two b's, as two is larger than one.

Comment: @Thomas Oh god. I'm sorry. I mean m times V is m is LESS than n and n times V if n is LESS than m. So like if object  x  occurs ﬁve times in one bag and twice in another, the intersection of these bags contains  x  two times

Comment: @robmayoff I think my last post answers your question.

Comment: It doesn't.  I am asking about the vector returned by the `toVector` method.  How many times does the return value of `toVector` contain `"Joker"` if the bag contains it 3 times?

Comment: @robmayoff Here's my specification /** Empties and then fills a given vector with all entries that
are in this bag
return A vector containing all the entries in the bag */ So 3

Comment: @JohnPeterson: I'd get rid of `Bag` completely. It appears to provide little (nothing?) that `std::multiset` won't do at least as well. Using `std::multiset`, the answer would be to use `std::set_intersection`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin How would I do that code wise?

Comment: @JohnPeterson: If you can't get rid of Bag, you should probably at least provide a wrapper (or modify it internally) to conform to the standard interface for an (ordered) collection, so you can still use `std::set_intersection`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only way to enumerate the items in a bag is by using `toVector`, you need to iterate over the `toVector` of one of your input bags.  For each item, take the minimum frequency of that item in either of the input bags, and make sure the output bag contains the item with that frequency.  Since the `toVector` might contain the same item repeatedly, you have to check the output bag to see if it already contains the item you're considering.

I'm not up to speed on C++11, so I'll just do this an old-fashioned way:

```
template<class T>
Bag<T> intersection(BagInterface<T> const &a, BagInterface<T> const &b) {
    Bag<T> c;
    std::vector<T> aItems = a.toVector();
    for (int i = 0; i < aItems.size(); ++i) {
        T const &item = aItems[i];
        int needed = std::min(a.getFrequencyOf(item), b.getFrequencyOf(item));
        int lacking = needed - c.getFrequencyOf(item);
        for ( ; lacking > 0; --lacking) {
            c.add(item);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand what you did here. I am new to c++ in general. I see you used the toVector to do your stuff but my task is to make a brand new method to accomplish the task :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using enum for clubs. You can use strings, but string comparsion is tricky.

```
enum ClubsType { 
    Joker, 
    Ace, 
    Two, 
    Three, 
    Four, 
    Five, 
    Six, 
    Seven, 
    Eight, 
    Nine, 
    Ten, 
    Jack, 
    Queen, 
    King,
    ClubsTypeSize
}

Bag<ClubsType> Intersection(const Bag<ClubsType>& other) {
    set<ClubsType> common;
    int n = v.size();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        common.insert(v[i]);
    }
    otherAsVector = other.toVector();
    n = otherAsVector.size();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        common.insert(otherAsVector[i]);
    }
    Bag<ClubsType> result;
    for (set<ClubsType>::iterator it = common.begin(); it!=common.end();++it) {
        result.add(*it);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) from [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) does this for sorted input ranges:

```
vector<int> as { 1, 2, 3 };
vector<int> bs { 2, 3, 4 };
vector<int> cs;

set_intersection(
    begin(as), end(as),
    begin(bs), end(bs),
    back_inserter(cs)
);

// 2 3
for (const auto c : cs)
    cout << c << ' ';
```

It works by looping over the input ranges until at least one is exhausted, copying those elements from one range that appear in the other, according to the strict weak ordering imposed by `operator<`:

```
while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
    if (*first1 < *first2) {
        ++first1;
    } else {
        if (!(*first2 < *first1)) {
            *output++ = *first1++;
        }
        ++first2;
    }
}
return output;
```